# How to apply a user defined function to multiple columns in BigQuery SQL?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

In the database I'm working on there are a several wage variables that are recorded as strings with entries like `0000001155,00`. I am using a combination of `CAST` and `REPLACE` to transform these variables into float. For just one variable, I used:

```
 CAST (REPLACE (wage_var, ",", ".") AS float64) as wage_formatted
```

I would like to perform this procedure for all variables that have the same problem, without repeating the same line of code. My idea is to use a function and then iterate the function through the columns.

I figure out how I can create a function to perform the standardization after reading the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/user-defined-functions). Then I wrote the following function:

```sql
CREATE TEMP FUNCTION wage2float(x STRING) AS (CAST(REPLACE(x, ",", ".") AS float64));
SELECT
  wage_var,
  wage2float(wage_var) as wage_formatted
FROM
  `mydataset.mytable`
```

However, it's not clear to me how I can iterate this function on several columns. Is there a way to loop through the columns and apply the `wage2float` function for each column?

**EDIT:**

Here is sample of input (csv):

```
vl_remun_media_nom,vl_remun_media_sm,vl_remun_dezembro_nom,vl_remun_dezembro_sm,vl_ultima_remuneracao_ano,vl_salario_contratual,vl_rem_janeiro_cc,vl_rem_fevereiro_cc,vl_rem_marco_cc,vl_rem_abril_cc,vl_rem_maio_cc,vl_rem_junho_cc,vl_rem_julho_cc,vl_rem_agosto_cc,vl_rem_setembro_cc,vl_rem_outubro_cc,vl_rem_novembro_cc
"0000006025,55","000006,42","0000005921,09","000006,31","0005921,09","0005148,77","000000005866,27","000000005866,27","000000005866,27","000000005866,27","000000005866,27","000000005866,27","000000007169,88","000000006254,78","000000005921,09","000000005921,09","000000005921,09"
"0000001447,68","000001,54","0000001726,67","000001,84","0001726,67","0000014,00","000000001645,55","000000000014,00","000000000014,00","000000000014,00","000000000014,00","000000000014,00","000000000014,00","000000000014,00","000000000014,00","000000000014,00","000000000014,00"
"0000001304,35","000001,39","0000001304,35","000001,39","0001304,35","0001304,35","000000000000,00","000000000000,00","000000000000,00","000000000000,00","000000000000,00","000000000000,00","000000000000,00","000000001304,35","000000001304,35","000000001304,35","000000001304,35"
"0000001447,68","000001,54","0000001726,67","000001,84","0001726,67","0000014,00","000000001645,55","000000000014,00","000000000014,00","000000000014,00","000000000014,00","000000000014,00","000000000014,00","000000000014,00","000000000014,00","000000000014,00","000000000014,00"
"0000001447,68","000001,54","0000001726,67","000001,84","0001726,67","0000014,00","000000001645,56","000000000014,00","000000000014,00","000000000014,00","000000000014,00","000000000014,00","000000000014,00","000000000014,00","000000000014,00","000000000014,00","000000000014,00"
"0000001447,68","000001,54","0000001726,67","000001,84","0001726,67","0000014,00","000000001645,55","000000000014,00","000000000014,00","000000000014,00","000000000014,00","000000000014,00","000000000014,00","000000000014,00","000000000014,00","000000000014,00","000000000014,00"
"0000001427,95","000001,52","0000001420,68","000001,51","0001420,68","0001420,68","000000001379,30","000000001379,30","000000001379,30","000000001379,30","000000001379,30","000000001379,30","000000001839,07","000000001379,30","000000001379,30","000000001420,68","000000001420,68"
"0000005937,88","000006,33","0000005900,00","000006,29","0005900,00","0000059,00","000000000057,38","000000000057,38","000000000057,38","000000000057,38","000000007650,67","000000000057,38","000000000057,38","000000000057,38","000000000057,38","000000000059,00","000000000059,00"
"0000001087,04","000001,15","0000001076,20","000001,14","0001076,20","0001076,20","000000000010,00","000000000010,00","000000000010,00","000000001076,20","000000001076,20","000000001076,20","000000001076,20","000000001434,93","000000001076,20","000000001076,20","000000001076,20"
"0000002395,30","000002,55","0000002448,79","000002,61","0002448,79","0002448,79","000000002377,47","000000002377,47","000000002377,47","000000002377,47","000000002377,47","000000002377,47","000000002377,47","000000002377,47","000000002377,47","000000002448,79","000000002448,79"
"0000001870,56","000001,99","0000001820,00","000001,94","0001820,00","0000018,00","000000001820,01","000000001820,01","000000001820,01","000000001820,01","000000001820,01","000000000018,20","000000000018,20","000000000018,20","000000000018,20","000000002426,67","000000000018,20"
"0000002960,08","000003,15","0000003068,59","000003,27","0003068,59","0000027,00","000000002724,53","000000002500,09","000000003454,64","000000002700,88","000000002943,15","000000002943,42","000000002943,69","000000003098,28","000000003098,24","000000002976,73","000000003068,79"
"0000003798,04","000004,04","0000003852,69","000004,11","0003852,69","0000030,00","000000002500,45","000000002500,57","000000002500,79","000000005306,55","000000005079,02","000000003430,02","000000004239,21","000000004182,29","000000004913,02","000000003247,38","000000003824,52"
"0000004945,06","000005,27","0000005286,81","000005,64","0005286,81","0000045,00","000000004000,10","000000004000,16","000000005392,43","000000004919,14","000000004500,98","000000004500,21","000000005936,10","000000006133,08","000000004795,43","000000004576,91","000000005299,44"
"0000005810,00","000006,19","0000005540,00","000005,91","0005540,00","0000055,40","000000006933,33","000000000055,40","000000000055,40","000000000055,40","000000000055,40","000000000055,40","000000000055,40","000000007386,67","000000000055,40","000000000055,40","000000000055,40"
"0000001103,62","000001,17","0000001090,00","000001,16","0001090,00","0000010,90","000000000010,31","000000000010,31","000000000010,31","000000001086,20","000000001086,20","000000001086,20","000000001086,20","000000001086,20","000000001086,20","000000001453,33","000000000010,90"
"0000002600,34","000002,77","0000002866,13","000003,05","0002866,13","0000010,91","000000000000,00","000000000000,00","000000000000,00","000000000000,00","000000002168,92","000000001999,70","000000002175,13","000000003036,83","000000002909,14","000000002887,45","000000002759,44"
"0000005174,66","000005,51","0000004967,86","000005,30","0004967,86","0000016,15","000000005154,31","000000004621,59","000000005161,25","000000005080,73","000000005185,34","000000004981,24","000000006430,29","000000005584,57","000000005064,43","000000005029,16","000000004835,26"
"0000005693,03","000006,07","0000005650,78","000006,03","0005650,78","0005650,78","000000005433,44","000000005433,44","000000005433,44","000000005433,44","000000007244,59","000000005433,44","000000005433,44","000000005868,12","000000005650,78","000000005650,78","000000005650,78"
"0000002485,76","000002,64","0000002810,52","000002,99","0002810,52","0000010,91","000000002193,56","000000001925,13","000000002352,46","000000002135,21","000000002440,66","000000002232,19","000000002951,81","000000002947,97","000000002588,45","000000002516,61","000000002734,59"
"0000003808,35","000004,06","0000003893,40","000004,15","0003893,40","0003893,40","000000000037,80","000000000037,80","000000000037,80","000000000037,80","000000000037,80","000000000037,80","000000000037,80","000000000037,80","000000000037,80","000000000037,80","000000004006,80"
"0000004648,00","000004,95","0000004549,71","000004,85","0004549,71","0004549,71","000000004212,70","000000004549,71","000000006066,28","000000004549,71","000000004549,71","000000004549,71","000000004549,71","000000004549,71","000000004549,71","000000004549,71","000000004549,71"
"0000004521,62","000004,82","0000004549,71","000004,85","0004549,71","0004549,71","000000004212,70","000000004549,71","000000004549,71","000000004549,71","000000004549,71","000000004549,71","000000004549,71","000000004549,71","000000004549,71","000000004549,71","000000004549,71"
"0000003024,00","000003,22","0000003024,00","000003,22","0003024,00","0000030,24","000000000028,00","000000000028,00","000000000028,00","000000000028,00","000000000039,20","000000000030,24","000000000030,24","000000000030,24","000000000030,24","000000000030,24","000000000030,24"
"0000002946,43","000003,14","0000002910,00","000003,10","0002910,00","0001923,68","000000000000,00","000000000000,00","000000000000,00","000000000000,00","000000000000,00","000000000000,00","000000000000,00","000000000000,00","000000000000,00","000000002983,70","000000002945,59"
```

Desired output:

```
vl_remun_media_nom,vl_remun_media_sm,vl_remun_dezembro_nom,vl_remun_dezembro_sm,vl_ultima_remuneracao_ano,vl_salario_contratual,vl_rem_janeiro_cc,vl_rem_fevereiro_cc,vl_rem_marco_cc,vl_rem_abril_cc,vl_rem_maio_cc,vl_rem_junho_cc,vl_rem_julho_cc,vl_rem_agosto_cc,vl_rem_setembro_cc,vl_rem_outubro_cc,vl_rem_novembro_cc
6025.55,6.42,5921.09,6.31,5921.09,5148.77,5866.27,5866.27,5866.27,5866.27,5866.27,5866.27,7169.88,6254.78,5921.09,5921.09,5921.09
1447.68,1.54,1726.67,1.84,1726.67,14.0,1645.55,14.0,14.0,14.0,14.0,14.0,14.0,14.0,14.0,14.0,14.0
1304.35,1.39,1304.35,1.39,1304.35,1304.35,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,1304.35,1304.35,1304.35,1304.35
1447.68,1.54,1726.67,1.84,1726.67,14.0,1645.55,14.0,14.0,14.0,14.0,14.0,14.0,14.0,14.0,14.0,14.0
1447.68,1.54,1726.67,1.84,1726.67,14.0,1645.56,14.0,14.0,14.0,14.0,14.0,14.0,14.0,14.0,14.0,14.0
1447.68,1.54,1726.67,1.84,1726.67,14.0,1645.55,14.0,14.0,14.0,14.0,14.0,14.0,14.0,14.0,14.0,14.0
1427.95,1.52,1420.68,1.51,1420.68,1420.68,1379.3,1379.3,1379.3,1379.3,1379.3,1379.3,1839.07,1379.3,1379.3,1420.68,1420.68
5937.88,6.33,5900.0,6.29,5900.0,59.0,57.38,57.38,57.38,57.38,7650.67,57.38,57.38,57.38,57.38,59.0,59.0
1087.04,1.15,1076.2,1.14,1076.2,1076.2,10.0,10.0,10.0,1076.2,1076.2,1076.2,1076.2,1434.93,1076.2,1076.2,1076.2
2395.3,2.55,2448.79,2.61,2448.79,2448.79,2377.47,2377.47,2377.47,2377.47,2377.47,2377.47,2377.47,2377.47,2377.47,2448.79,2448.79
1870.56,1.99,1820.0,1.94,1820.0,18.0,1820.01,1820.01,1820.01,1820.01,1820.01,18.2,18.2,18.2,18.2,2426.67,18.2
2960.08,3.15,3068.59,3.27,3068.59,27.0,2724.53,2500.09,3454.64,2700.88,2943.15,2943.42,2943.69,3098.28,3098.24,2976.73,3068.79
3798.04,4.04,3852.69,4.11,3852.69,30.0,2500.45,2500.57,2500.79,5306.55,5079.02,3430.02,4239.21,4182.29,4913.02,3247.38,3824.52
4945.06,5.27,5286.81,5.64,5286.81,45.0,4000.1,4000.16,5392.43,4919.14,4500.98,4500.21,5936.1,6133.08,4795.43,4576.91,5299.44
5810.0,6.19,5540.0,5.91,5540.0,55.4,6933.33,55.4,55.4,55.4,55.4,55.4,55.4,7386.67,55.4,55.4,55.4
1103.62,1.17,1090.0,1.16,1090.0,10.9,10.31,10.31,10.31,1086.2,1086.2,1086.2,1086.2,1086.2,1086.2,1453.33,10.9
2600.34,2.77,2866.13,3.05,2866.13,10.91,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,2168.92,1999.7,2175.13,3036.83,2909.14,2887.45,2759.44
5174.66,5.51,4967.86,5.3,4967.86,16.15,5154.31,4621.59,5161.25,5080.73,5185.34,4981.24,6430.29,5584.57,5064.43,5029.16,4835.26
5693.03,6.07,5650.78,6.03,5650.78,5650.78,5433.44,5433.44,5433.44,5433.44,7244.59,5433.44,5433.44,5868.12,5650.78,5650.78,5650.78
2485.76,2.64,2810.52,2.99,2810.52,10.91,2193.56,1925.13,2352.46,2135.21,2440.66,2232.19,2951.81,2947.97,2588.45,2516.61,2734.59
3808.35,4.06,3893.4,4.15,3893.4,3893.4,37.8,37.8,37.8,37.8,37.8,37.8,37.8,37.8,37.8,37.8,4006.8
4648.0,4.95,4549.71,4.85,4549.71,4549.71,4212.7,4549.71,6066.28,4549.71,4549.71,4549.71,4549.71,4549.71,4549.71,4549.71,4549.71
4521.62,4.82,4549.71,4.85,4549.71,4549.71,4212.7,4549.71,4549.71,4549.71,4549.71,4549.71,4549.71,4549.71,4549.71,4549.71,4549.71
3024.0,3.22,3024.0,3.22,3024.0,30.24,28.0,28.0,28.0,28.0,39.2,30.24,30.24,30.24,30.24,30.24,30.24
2946.43,3.14,2910.0,3.1,2910.0,1923.68,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,2983.7,2945.59
```

Comment: please provide sample of input data and respective expected output - see [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: do you want/have ALL columns to be processed in such a way - or you want to supply list of columns that needs to be processed? both cases easily doable but slightly different  - so let know which one is yours

Comment: No. Just the columns starting with `vl`. There are several other variables which didn't need this procedure

Comment: ok. should be simple :o) - will post answer later in a day

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Just the columns starting with vl. There are several other variables which didn't need this procedure

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL and uses BQ Scripting

```
execute immediate (select 'select * replace(' || 
  string_agg('cast(replace(' || column || ', ",", ".") as float64) as ' || column, ', ') || 
  ') from YourTable'
from (
  select regexp_extract_all(to_json_string(t), r'"(vl_[^"]*)":') as columns
  from YourTable t
  limit 1
), unnest(columns) column);
```

if to apply to below simplified example (it still fully represent OP's use case):

```
select 1 id, "0000006025,55" vl_x, "000006,42" y, "0000005921,09" vl_z union all
select 2, "0000001447,68", "000001,54", "0000001726,67"
```

[image]

output is

[image]

You should click on <kbd>VIEW RESULTS</kbd> of last row to see final result

[image]

Depends on what you want then to do with result - you can adjust code to replace YourTable with this output or create new one, etc. See example of such adjustment (just first line - the rest are the same)

```
execute immediate (select 'create table NewTable as select * replace(' || 
. . .
```

Comment: please note update I just did - I realized - I missed (typo) `*` in one place of regexp

Comment: Thanks. It works. I'm a newbie in BQ then it takes a while until I figure out how I should run the script. I create a file called `format_wage.sql` with the script content, then I ran in gcloud shell `bq query --use_legacy_sql=false --flagfile=format_wage.sql`. Perhaps this information will be useful for some future readers of this question

Answer (score 0):

If you want a `select` query, you would just use:

```
SELECT CAST(REPLACE(wage_var, ',', '.') AS float64) as wage_formatted,
       CAST(REPLACE(taxes_var, ',', '.') AS float64) as taxes_formatted,
       . . . 
FROM t;
```

If you want to do this "permanently" . . . well, I would suggest a view:

```
CREATE VIEW v_t AS
    SELECT t.*,
           CAST(REPLACE(wage_var, ',', '.') AS float64) as wage_formatted,
           CAST(REPLACE(taxes_var, ',', '.') AS float64) as taxes_formatted,
           . . . 
    FROM t;
```

You could also add new columns into the table and give them the floating point value.

Comment: Ok. But do I need to repeat the lines? I mean, there is no way to create a list of columns and then iterate through the list?